# H2O H2OServerError: HTTP 500 Server Error when training model

Tags: h2o

Trying to train a DRF classifier in h2o (version 3.20.0.5), the error "H2OServerError: HTTP 500 Server Error" with no further explanation.

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
H2OServerError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-f52d1cb4b77a> in <module>()
      4     training_frame=train_u, validation_frame=val_u,
      5     weights_column='weight',
----> 6     max_runtime_secs=max_train_time_hrs*60*60)
      7 
      8 

/home/mapr/python-virtual-envs/ml1c/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h2o/estimators/estimator_base.pyc in train(self, x, y, training_frame, offset_column, fold_column, weights_column, validation_frame, max_runtime_secs, ignored_columns, model_id, verbose)
    224         rest_ver = parms.pop("_rest_version") if "_rest_version" in parms else 3
    225 
--> 226         model_builder_json = h2o.api("POST /%d/ModelBuilders/%s" % (rest_ver, self.algo), data=parms)
    227         model = H2OJob(model_builder_json, job_type=(self.algo + " Model Build"))
    228 

/home/mapr/python-virtual-envs/ml1c/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h2o/h2o.pyc in api(endpoint, data, json, filename, save_to)
    101     # type checks are performed in H2OConnection class
    102     _check_connection()
--> 103     return h2oconn.request(endpoint, data=data, json=json, filename=filename, save_to=save_to)
    104 
    105 

/home/mapr/python-virtual-envs/ml1c/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h2o/backend/connection.pyc in request(self, endpoint, data, json, filename, save_to)
    400                                     auth=self._auth, verify=self._verify_ssl_cert, proxies=self._proxies)
    401             self._log_end_transaction(start_time, resp)
--> 402             return self._process_response(resp, save_to)
    403 
    404         except (requests.exceptions.ConnectionError, requests.exceptions.HTTPError) as e:

/home/mapr/python-virtual-envs/ml1c/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h2o/backend/connection.pyc in _process_response(response, save_to)
    728         # Note that it is possible to receive valid H2OErrorV3 object in this case, however it merely means the server
    729         # did not provide the correct status code.
--> 730         raise H2OServerError("HTTP %d %s:\n%r" % (status_code, response.reason, data))
    731 
    732 

H2OServerError: HTTP 500 Server Error:
Server error java.lang.NullPointerException:
  Error: Caught exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
  Request: None
```

The code snippet in question is shown below:

```py
max_train_time_hrs = 8 
drf_proc.train(
    x=train_features, y=train_response,
    training_frame=train_u, validation_frame=val_u,
    weights_column='weight',
    max_runtime_secs=max_train_time_hrs*60*60)
```

The output from running the `h2o.init()` command looks like

```
Checking whether there is an H2O instance running at http://172.18.4.62:54321. connected.
Warning: Your H2O cluster version is too old (7 months and 24 days)! Please download and install the latest version from http://h2o.ai/download/
H2O cluster uptime: 06 secs
H2O cluster timezone:   Pacific/Honolulu
H2O data parsing timezone:  UTC
H2O cluster version:    3.20.0.5
H2O cluster version age:    7 months and 24 days !!!
H2O cluster name:   H2O_88021
H2O cluster total nodes:    4
H2O cluster free memory:    15.34 Gb
H2O cluster total cores:    8
H2O cluster allowed cores:  8
H2O cluster status: accepting new members, healthy
H2O connection url: http://172.18.4.62:54321
H2O connection proxy:   None
H2O internal security:  False
H2O API Extensions: AutoML, XGBoost, Algos, Core V3, Core V4
Python version: 2.7.12 fin
```

While I realize that there is a warning that the version of h2o I am using is "too old", the version of the h2o python package I am using and the cluster I am connecting to still match and this cannot be upgraded due to other h2o applications that access this cluster and expect a certain version (all of these applications appear to have no problem running on the cluster). Meanwhile, any web browser is unable to connect to the H2O connection url.

Any ideas about what could be going on here or debugging steps that could be looked into?

Comment: Can you replicate this bug using a reproducible example?

Comment: @ErinLeDell Part of the difficulty I was having with this problem was that there are several other applications that work fine with very similar code and there is a good amount of preprocessing and other steps in the code that happen before training, making it difficult to get a good clean example of the same kind of error (would probably have a lot more that could debug on own if had that though). Will continue trying to get more information though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

15GB of memory might not be enough for a training process you expect to last 8hrs. (Aside: I'd recommend using [early stopping](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/stopping_rounds.html), rather than, or as well as, `max_runtime_secs`.)

As a debugging step, I would recommend watching in the Flow interface (point your browser to port 54321 - see the connection URL in your `h2o.init()` output). Especially watch how memory usage is rising over time.

(Sometimes a "500" error just means it has gone unstable, and lack of memory is a common trigger.)

If you are getting the error immediately, that is less likely to be the problem (unless you have a huge dataset).

In that case I'd try to narrow down if a particular column or data row could be causing the problem. E.g.

- Experiment 1: first half of columns in `train_features`
- Experiment 2: second half of columns in `train_features`
- Experiment 3: first half of rows in `train_u`
- Experiment 4: second half of rows in `train_u`
- Experiment 5/6 (if still no luck): the same for `valid_u`

If one of the experiment pair crashes but the other doesn't, then repeat the experiment on the crashing half.

Comment: Thanks for the debugging avenues. What worked was opening the browser to h2o connection url (could not do previously for still unknown reason) and check logs in the Admin>View Logs tab. Was able to connect to the url from VM developing in, but not from browser on the host. Any reason for this? Main problem ultimately due to a variable passing wrong value to the `weights_column` param in the `model.train(.)` call (embarrassingly, doubt my *specific* solution is useful to most people). Any reason why a `weights_column` must be specified at both model instantiation *and* in the `.train()` call?

Comment: @lampShadesDrifter According to the python example at http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/weights_column.html you only need to give it in the `train()` call.